# Pause/resume video based on focus

Tags: android, video

I have a videoview that plays as a background. How do I pause it when my app looses focus and resume the video when the app has focus again? Here is my code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher);

    VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.launcherVideo);
    Uri src = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.package/raw/video");
    videoView.setVideoURI(src);

    videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
            mp.setLooping(true);
        }
    });

    //videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));

    videoView.start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
override onPause() method and write code for pause on that method and override onResume() method and write code for resume on that method
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm a beginner though. I don't know how to write the code for the pause and resume.

Comment: mediaplayer.pause(); and mediaplayer.start();

Comment: I'm not sure if this is correct but this is what I came up with. `@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mediaplayer.pause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mediaplayer.start();
    }`